# unit test LogstashEncoder is configured correctly

Tags: java, mockito, logback, kotlin, logstash-logback-encoder

I want to have a unit test in place to verify that the LogstashEncoder is configured correctly and produces JSON formatted logs 
=> logstash-logback-encoder must be registered as a dependency and a logback.xml must be configured.

Trying out the @Captor as described here http://bloodredsun.com/2014/06/03/checking-logback-based-logging-in-unit-tests/ I can only test the content of the *message* but not its *format*.

In my concrete case I'm logging the following info: `LOG.info("my demo log")`

which generates the following log output:
`{"@timestamp":"2017-01-15T21:43:41.295+01:00","@version":1,"message":"my demo log message","logger_name":"org.sample.project.Application","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"HOSTNAME":"tee"}`

But as written above `loggingEvent.getFormattedMessage()` returns just the message string `my demo log`.

So what's the trick to get the json formatted message from the LoggingEvent?

Thanks and best regards!